# lvmcache/dm-cache and discards on Linux kernel 4.7.x

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, lvm, cache

I have a 200GB LVM volume that is backed by a 60GB SSD using [`lvmcache(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html), on Linux kernel version 4.7.2. I have been experimenting with `fstrim`, and it seems to me that discards are not working as they should (or at all):

```
$ df /dev/mapper/vg0-test
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-test  199G   46G  143G  25% /media/test
# lsblk -D /dev/mapper/vg0-test
NAME     DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
vg0-test        0       16M      16G         0
# fstrim -v  /media/test
/media/test: 132.4 GiB (142170128384 bytes) trimmed
# lvs -o+devices,cache_total_blocks,cache_used_blocks,cache_dirty_blocks,cache_read_hits,cache_read_misses,cache_write_hits,cache_write_misses,segtype,discards
  LV      VG  Attr       LSize   Pool            Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices          CacheTotalBlocks CacheUsedBlocks  CacheDirtyBlocks CacheReadHits    CacheReadMisses  CacheWriteHits   CacheWriteMisses Type  Discards
  test    vg0 Cwc-aoC--- 200.00g [test-cache]           100.00 23.83           0.00             test_corig(0)              983040           983040               39         44554204          5209836         79687783          2798870 cache
```

I was hoping that, since the space actually in use is less than the size of the cache, using `fstrim` would allow lvmcache to get rid of unused cached data blocks and also TRIM the underlying SSD. Yet that does not seem to happen.

1. Is what I am expecting even supported in the kernel version that I have? Reading the DM and block layer code is not trivial, so I'd rather not figure that out the hard way if possible.
2. If it is supported, is something wrong with my LVM setup? I believe that the default LVM behavior w.r.t. discards is to pass them down to the underlying device, but maybe there is something that I am missing?

Comment: To clarify: You expect the TRIM to be passed down to your SSD *and* to decrease the amount of used blocks of the cache?

Comment: maxf: well, TRIM is a low-level ATA command, so it's the very final result; that the relevant ioctl is called `FITRIM` is an unfortunate coincidence IMHO. I was more thinking of block discards on LVM thin pools (with which a dm-cache pool shares several features), where discarded blocks return to the VG free pool and the underlying storage is, well, TRIM'ed (or UNMAP'ed or...). In any case I have a cache with 60GB of data mapped to 46GB of actual data; there's some obvious room for improvement there.

Comment: BTW, if I ever find the poor b****rd that first thought of using base-10 units for computer storage, I'll <violent-act/> them. You can never be quite sure anymore whether any random G or M is base-10 or base-2...